# Java - finding - prime number or not

Tags: java, eclipse

using Eclipse, Java

Try to make method for checking whether a number is prime (means can be devided by1 and by himself) or not

Currently was created some functionality (code below). This code return required result, but not for all numbers that are prime, means for number 33 and 55 it's return `false` instead of `true`.

Code

```
private static void numberCheker() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter number - ");
    int number;
    number = getNumber();
    boolean result = true;
    if ((number % 2 == 0) && (number != 2)) {
        System.out.println("Not");
    } else if (number == 1) {
        System.out.println("1 not a valid number");    
    } else if (number == 2)
        System.out.println("Simple");    
    else {
        for (int i = 2; i < number + 1; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                result = false;
            } else
                result = true;
        }
        if (result = true)
            System.out.println("Simple");    
        else 
            System.out.println("not Simple");
    }
}
```

The **question** - where i'm make mistake in my "logic" - spend few hours for fixing - but cant do that. Any suggestion?

Result must be like below

```
Enter number - 
1
simple
Enter number - 
2
simple
Enter number - 
3
simple
Enter number - 
4
not simple
Enter number - 
5
simple
```

...

but i got

```
Enter number - 
33
not simple - **WRONG**
Enter number - 
55
not simple - **WRONG**
```

---

**EDIT:**

many thanks all
try to do like Michael Konietzka sad:

```
 private static boolean numberCheker() throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Enter number - ");
    int number = getNumber();

    for (int i=2;i<number;i++)
     {
        if (number%i==0) return false; 
     }
        return (number>1);
```

}

and getNumber()

```
public static int getNumber () throws IOException{
int temp;
try{    
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String resultReader = bReader.readLine();
    temp =  Integer.parseInt(resultReader);
    return temp;
}
catch (NumberFormatException failDescription){
    System.out.println(failDescription);
    return 0;
}
```

}

now its work perfect
Thanks for your help!

Comment: "*cant find error*", where is the question?

Comment: What is the definition of a simple number?

Comment: `Please help - spend 3 hours - cant find error.. Code` -> What, squashed everything into one single sentence?

Comment: What do you mean by `simple number`? Not a complex number? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

Comment: Can you define a "simple number"?  Maybe I haven't taken a math course in awhile, but I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: This looks like a prime number check, but we can't tell for sure.  Please explain your error in the op.

Comment: q: - where is error in my code - when you use it it can tell you that number 99 for example its simple - but its wrong

Comment: 99 is not a prime number. 3 * 33 = 99(not a simple number)

Comment: sim[le number like - 1 2 3 5 7 11...

Comment: @Bki there is no error in your code.. for 99 as the input, your program is giving the correct output

Comment: 99 not a simple - but my program return simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may put the check in a static method of your class:

```
public static boolean isPrime(final int n)
    {
     for (int i=2;i<n;i++)
     {
        if (n%i==0) return false; 
     }
        return (n>1);
    }
```

You must iterate trough all numbers from 2 to n-1 and check, if n is divisible by i without remainder. If so, the method can return immediately false, because one factor was found. If no factor is found between 2 and n-1 and the number is greater 1 it is a prime; the method returns true.

To use this method you can use it simple this way for example:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
     for (int i=1;i<10;i++)
     {
         System.out.println(i+": "+isPrime(i));
     }
```

which will output

> 1: false
>
> 2: true
>
> 3: true
>
> 4: false
>
> 5: true
>
> 6: false
>
> 7: true
>
> 8: false
>
> 9: false

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what is the definition of simple number

but this could be a problem

```
 if (result=true)
```

change above to

```
 if (result)
```

**EDIT** You also need to fix loopholes mentioned by others.

Comment: or `if (result == true)`

Comment: That shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @EAKAE `if(result==true)` is nothing but  `if (result)` as `result` is boolean. So it could be either true or false

Comment: I know they're the same, It's a matter of personal preference.  Some ide's mark it as a warning though (I think).

Comment: @mikeTheLiar This will compile fine. Its a boolean assignment, so eventually result become true. But yes if its something other than boolean it will not compile.

Comment: I had no idea that rule doesn't apply to booleans. All the more reason to never write `if(someBooleanValue == true)`

Comment: @mikeTheLiar As @ EAKAE said. Its just matter of personnel preferences.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (result=true)
```

I think you meant the double equal sign:

```
if (result==true)
```

When you say if (result=true), this statement will always return true.

EDIT: You'll also need to fix the if-else content in the for loop. See Mr.Me's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not breaking out of the loop when you find that the number is not prime, to solve this just add, break; after your if statment ... here is the code:

```
        if (number%i==0){
            result=false;
             break;
            }
```

**Edit**

Also you need to fix the if statement as @Smit is suggesting

Answer (score 0):

3 is a prime but multiples of 3 are not prime, ditto for 5 etc. Multiples of primes are not primes. there are only so many prime nos. no definitive rule has been developed for devising primes, i doubt if you will do it.
a prime no is a number that is not in the set 2n n 3n and that is divisble only by itself and 1.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues 
1 - you need to add a break when its false
2 - need to change the if in the end

```
   if (result=true)
```

to

```
   if (result)

public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter number - ");
        int number = 55;
        boolean result = true;
        if ((number%2==0) && (number!=2) ){
            System.out.println("Not");
            }
        else if (number ==1){
            System.out.println("1 not a valid number"); 
        }
        else if (number ==2)
            System.out.println("Simple");   
        else{           
            for (int i=2; i<number;i++){
                if (number%i==0){
                    result=false;
                    break;
                    }
                else
                    result = true;

                }
            if (result)
                System.out.println("Simple");   
            else 
                System.out.println("not Simple");
        }   

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is in the loop termination.

By looping until number + 1, the number will eventually be divided by itself, leaving a remainder of zero, so every number will be appear to be not prime.

Loop until number / 2 instead (sqrt(number) would be more efficient, but the quality of your code suggests this isn't a concern)

Also you must break out if the loop when you detect a remainder of zero.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at an algorithm called the Sieve of Erathosthenes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

It is a quite simple algorithm to create a list of primes and will help you understand how finding out whether a number is prime or not is determined.

BTW - don't forget to rule out negative numbers!